# FIDO U2F: independence of signature method?

Tags: authentication, fido-u2f, yubico

Can the FIDO U2F standard be implemented with an arbitrary signature method? I couldn't find any information if a specific method needs to be used.

Further question: is it possible to send multiple public keys to the relying party at the registration step (e.g. if a one-time signing scheme is used).

Answer (score 1):

No, FIDO U2F uses ecdsa signatures with der encoding
During registration only one public key can be sent. Nevertheless you can register multiple tokens to one account but by performing multiple registrations. https://fidoalliance.org/specifications/download/